# white screen after lid close

Tags: suspend, laptop, hibernate

I am running Ubuntu (server I think) on an HP laptop.  I would like, when I close the lid, for it to lock, but what happens instead is (after a few minutes of lid being closed) I get a blank white screen.  Hitting space bar or moving mouse has no effect.  I was unable to find a fix in power settings there is nothing there about lid closing.  I recall that I had this problem previously under Linux Mint, when I was a total novice with Linux, and the recommended fix had to do with adjusting the times for screen shutoff and hibernate (I think) to different times.  But under Ubuntu, I don't see the same options.  If you need more info, let me know.  I'm not sure what would be helpful and what wouldn't.

O.K., at Alexis Wilke's suggestion, I checked my graphics information.  I ran lshw under sudo.  It says, under *-cpu, I've got

AMD E2-7110 with AMD Radeon R2 Graphics

Then under *-display, it says

Mullins [Radeon R3 Graphics]

So it's probably R3.  Another development, I thought I'd found a fix, but it doesn't always work: sometimes, I can get back to my login screen from the white screen by pressing ctrl-alt-esc.  I don't have that activated for kill (not sure exactly how to do that but I mean to find out), but I figured I'd try it to see if it did anything, and at least once, it brought me to my login screen.  But not every time.

Comment: If you see X-Windows (a GUI) then you probably have Desktop only after installation you installed the GUI? Do you just see a black console on a cold reboot or windows with menus, icons, etc.?

Comment: I don't use Ubuntu on any laptop, but when you close a lid, in most cases, it will attempt an hibernation. It may also be called Sleep Mode. The lid probably generates an APIC signal or something of the sort to tell the OS that it was closed.

Comment: @Alexis Wilke, I think my desktop is called Gnome.  I only did one install for the O. S.  On a cold reboot, I get my unencrypt screen, followed by my login screen.  I am indeed talking about a hibernation, but when it wakes up from hibernate mode, the display is gone, and pure white.  Like, the computer wakes up but not the graphics card, or something.

For the most part, I find this version of Ubuntu quite stable for my laptop.

Comment: One thing you may want to indicate in your post (use the "edit" link) is the type of video board on your laptop. Is it an nVidia? They use a proprietary driver, usually, and it may have problems with that. Otherwise, what I've often seen are people who say they turned off the hibernate feature. Since i don't use it, I'm not too sure where it is. I only use a blank screen + DMS to turn of my desktop monitor.

Comment: I've added to my O.P.  Ideally, I'd like to set this to a definite behavior, if there's a way to do that.  I'd like to close my lid and be locked out, for security reasons, and then be able to get right back in with my password.  The current behavior seems more random -- I want to take control.